# Краш nano в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash

прохожу мануал https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-ubuntu-14-04-lts-ru

На четвертом шаге при выполнении команды `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` получаю поломку убунту 16.04, а именно: утилита `nano` постоянно после этого перезапускается и просит отправить отчет.
вот то, что получаетя в терминале сразу же после выполнения `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` :

```
b7758000-b7759000 r--p 00007000 08:03 11535757 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
b7759000-b775a000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 11535757 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
b775a000-b7761000 r--s 00000000 08:03 1843006 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b7761000-b7763000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7763000-b7765000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 [vvar]
b7765000-b7766000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]
b7766000-b7788000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 11535636 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7788000-b7789000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7789000-b778a000 r--p 00022000 08:03 11535636 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b778a000-b778b000 rw-p 00023000 08:03 11535636 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bff4b000-bff6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]
Аварийный останов (сделан дамп памяти)
```

Убунту привожу к нормальному состоянию в меню до загрузки системы (после биоса). как эту проблему решить?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `nano` редактор `vim`.

Comment: ну и ваще-то можете бросить тикет в digitalocean, если у вас там хостинг, а не просто учбеник используете

Comment: я хочу сначала научиться на локальной машине, а потом за хостинг заплатить. поробую нано переустановить. А что имеется в виду "вместо vim nano?" просто в команде заменять слово nano словом vim?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй собрать из исходников.
Скачай под свою систему https://www.nano-editor.org/download.php
распакуй

```
tar -xvf nano-2.6.3.tar.gz
./configure
make && make install
```